# Ordenação dos resultados de uma consulta - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Atualmente tenho um código que recebe dados das empresas cadastradas e para cada empresa ele lista os relatórios delas da seguinte forma:

```
@foreach($empresas as $empresa) // Recebe as empresas
   @foreach($empresa->CgrtInfo as $relatorio) // Busca Relatórios da empresa
      <tr>
         <td>{{ $relatorio->id }}</td>
         <td>{{ $relatorio->Empresa->razao_social }}</td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Estou fazendo a busca no Controller da seguinte forma:

```
$empresas = $cliente->Empresa()->where('razao_social', 'ILIKE', '%'.$busca.'%')->paginate(10);
```

Tabela CgrtInfo (Informações dos relatórios):

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('id_empresa')->unsigned();//Foreign key
$table->integer('id_cliente')->unsigned();//Foreign key
```

Tabela Empresa:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('id_cliente')->unsigned();//Foreign key
$table->string('razao_social', 128);
```

Model CgrtInfo:

```
public function Empresa(){ 
   return $this->belongsTo('SIST\Models\Client\Empresa', 'id_empresa'); 
}
```

Model Empresa:

```
public function CgrtInfo(){ 
   return $this->hasMany('SIST\Models\Client\Cgrt\CgrtInfo', 'id_empresa');
}
```

Só que dessa forma o id dos relatórios acaba ficando fora de ordem, pois se o relatório nº 10 foi da empresa 1, e o relatório 5 foi da empresa 2, acaba ficando o 10 na frente do 5.

> "Ah, e porque você não busca diretamente pelos relatórios?"

Sinceramente não consegui, pois quando a listagem é feita com base em uma busca, tenho que buscar pela razão social da empresa, e não tenho e nem achava necessário colocar essa informação no model de relatórios, mas se não tiver jeito...

Comment: Você poderia fazer isso num `SELECT` só no `Controller` ou `Model`, não sei onde está fazendo. Usa o `JOIN`, depois `ORDER BY` e ficará tudo na sequência. Daí na `view` você só controla com um `if` para mostrar a empresa uma vez.

Comment: Se quiser, poste a estrutura das tabelas e tentamos te ajudar

Comment: as tabelas são bem grandes, editei a pergunta e coloquei os campos que acredito ser relevantes. @Zoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá para trazer todos os relatórios num `SELECT`:

```
<?php 
    use DB;

    ...

    $relatorios = DB::table('CgrtInfo')
                      ->join('empresa', 'empresa.id', '=', 'CgrtInfo.id_empresa')
                      ->orderBy('empresa.id')
                      ->where('razao_social', 'ILIKE', '%'.$busca.'%')
                      ->paginate(10);

    ?>
```

Comment: Daí nem precisa usar o `belongsTo`, nesse caso.

Comment: blz, vou implementar qui pra ver

Comment: Quando fizer isso: `<td>{{ $relatorio->id }}</td>`, trará o `ID` do relatório por ser a principal tabela.

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou exatamente como eu precisava, vlw!

Comment: Boa. Que bom que você já sabia fazer o resto.

Comment: Alguns pequenos ajustes =)